# Change Default Web page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the file structure of my website

- app/view/home.php
- .index.php
- .htaccess

Now, I want to redirect the server to app/view/home.php if index.php is accessed.

By going to http://localhost/, the app/view/home.php must be the page to be served.

Thanks!

Comment: Does index.php do anything? Otherwise you could just put `include('app/view/home.php')` into it.

Comment: I turned index.php into a simple front controller using switch-case. Using the get method, the user will be redirected to a php file with the same get value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this in htaccess?

```
redirect 301 / http://localhost/app/view/home.php
```

Comment: might not work if you are using MVC tho. You can't access a view like that.

Answer (score -2):

I think this can be achieved by alias directive

```
Alias / /physical/path/to/file/apps/view/home.php
```

Comment: It's better to place in httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to achieve that using htaccess

Comment: This method is available in global server/virtual host context:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias but without alias everything you will be able to do is redirect